# Java: what's the proper way of storing grouped objects, accessible by their category?

Tags: java, sorting, object, grouping

I'm **grouping objects**, more complex than the example below, but I'm wondering if it's correct?

It works, but is there are **common pattern** (best practise) of doing so?

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> groupedItems = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

// Add some fruits
List fruits = new ArrayList();
fruits.add(new MyItem("Apple"));
fruits.add(new MyItem("Banana"));
groupedItems.put("fruits", fruits);

// Add some veggies
List veggies = new ArrayList();
veggies.add(new MyItem("Carrot"));
veggies.add(new MyItem("Potato"));
groupedItems.put("veggies", veggies);

// Select fruits
ArrayList fruits = groupedItems.get("fruits");
```

**Mod:** Please note that it's not really opinion-based, neither I'm asking for a code review. I'm looking for a **best practise**, because my way feels dirty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Warning:** you are using *raw types*, you should never use them.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Why do you think it's "dirty"?

Comment: @Maroun Thank you! I don't know if it's dirty, but it "feels" dirty. It's my first try and there might be a proper solution, that I don't know yet. It's mainly because I'm not having a perfect overview about alternatives to Map, HashMap, etc. and a lack of knowledge here.

Comment: @Mr.B. You're actually extending your knowledge by asking and looking for alternatives, keep it up! I would say go with this solution, if you'll have problems, post a more specific question. We'll be here to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively clean way of adding a new item to a multi-map:

```
groupedItems.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) Design Pattern for complex part whole relationship.